# Does Python come with numpy library as default

Tags: python, numpy

Does python come with numpy library as default or do you have to install it after installing python?

Comment: Regular ole CPython does not come with numpy.  You have to install it.

Comment: Try importing it and see

Comment: @ChrisFarr I already have my environment completely set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't come with numpy installed. However it could have been installed as requirement while installing other packages. 
You could install it via pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

Or, you could check the list of the installed packages and their version via pip:

```
pip list
```